# How to apply patches for updating VB.NET application over the internet?

Tags: vb.net

Hello dearest community,

First of all, I hope my intention is not missconcept.
I would like to add an update from the internet mechanism for my newly VB.NET application.
The idea is simple. That is, I ZIP all of the binary that need to be changed, upload it in my own hosting site, and download it using my Update Application, extract and overwrite the existing binary.

It works, quite well. But the problem is, the size of the binary itself is quite big (around 36MB). I am thinking of patches. That is, can we upload only the patch file, it surely make the download small isn't?

But I am not getting any good result on implementing it in Windows environment. 
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many files are in the zip? Is it one large executable, or is the zip only supposed to hold the files that have changed? If it only holds the files that changed, then expanding the zip should, theoretically, only overwrite the files contained in the .zip.

Also, is there a reason you're not using git, or some other DVCS to deploy just changes to your app? In addition to tracking code changes, they will intelligently apply just changes when using them as the source of deployments.

Comment: The zip contained several EXE. Yes, it works well.

I think the idea of using DVCS (D for Distributed I presumed?) is nice. Let me have a look of it more thoroughly.

Comment: I use your answer @normalocity. Having read this, http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git, it suite to my need well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

why reinvent the reinvent the wheel, Microsoft already provide a very good way of doing this called Click Once Deployment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Having read about it, I decided to go to what @normalocity had proposed. I love the idea! Thanks